# Bash function colouring from string input matching regex

Tags: colors, string

I have a multi-line string that I use for printing in a bash script.

```
docstring="
 Headings
  -H, -H CNT, -H=CNT, -HCNT, --heading CNT, --heading=CNT

 Warnings
  -W, -W CNT, -W=CNT, -WCNT, --warning CNT, --warning=CNT

 Errors
  -E, -E CNT, -E=CNT, -ECNT, --error CNT, --error=CNT"

echo "$docstring"
```

I want to make a function that takes this string and prints in colour
for lines starting with `-` or `{-`.

Thus, the following will be coloured

```
-H, -H CNT, -H=CNT, -HCNT, --heading CNT, --heading=CNT
-W, -W CNT, -W=CNT, -WCNT, --warning CNT, --warning=CNT
-E, -E CNT, -E=CNT, -ECNT, --error CNT, --error=CNT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), assuming the strings don't contain `\`, `` ` ``, `"` nor `$` characters:

```
printred(){ 
    sed -E 's/^ *\{?-.*/tput setaf 1;printf "%s" "&";tput sgr0/e' <<< "$@"
}
```

Usage:

```
printred "$docstring"
```

To choose another color, check:

```
for i in {0..7}; do
    tput setaf "$i"
    echo "tput setaf $i"
    tput sgr0
done
```

Caveats:

don't use as a CGI script as-is, keep it private, because, as pointed by Stephane Chazelas, you can run arbitrary command. This is to use in a trusted environment. Or make a kind of filter to sanitize input strings

Comment: A small inconvenience is that any starting whitespaces on matched lines are removed.

Comment: @Heime: fixed now

Comment: You forgot to handle watches starting with `{-`

Comment: @Heime: fixed too

Comment: Had to downvote. That calls one sh, two tputs, one echo (a command that can't be used for arbitrary data) for each matching line of input, and is a command injection vulnerability. Try for instance on the output of `echo '$(reboot)'` that `e` flag (a GNU extension) should really never have been introduced.

Comment: I would like to pass a predefined colour using `ctp` and `rst`.  So that I can do something similar to `sed -E 's/^ *\{?-.*/${ctp}; printf "%s\n" "&" ;${rst}/e' <<< "$@"`.  Cannot pass the variables this way though.

Comment: You need to inverse quotes. `sed -E "s/^ *\{?-.*/${ctp}; printf '%s\n' '&' ;${sgr}/e" <<< "$@"`

Comment: For some reason I am getting `sh: 2: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`.

Comment: Paste the full exact command here

Comment: `blu=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 39) ; rst=$(tput sgr0) ; ctp="$blue" ; sed -E "s/^ *\{?-.*/${ctp}; printf '%s\n' '&' ;${rst}/e" <<< "$@"`

Comment: `f() { ctp='tput bold; tput setaf 39'; rst='tput sgr0'; sed -E "s/^ *\{?-.*/${ctp}; printf '%s\n' '&';${rst}/e" <<< "$@"; }`

Comment: Why do you use `printf '%s\n'` because this is introducing an additional line on each new line of the string.

Comment: Try `printred '-$(uname)'` if you don't want to test `printred '-$(reboot)'`

Comment: @Heime: post edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

With the GNU implementation of `grep` or compatible:

```
grep --color -Ee '^\s*\{?-.*' -e '^' <<< "$docstring"
```

That's `grep`ping for lines starting with any number of whitespace character followed by an optional `{` followed by `-` followed by any number of characters, or just the start of the line, colouring what is matched as long as the output goes to a terminal device (assuming it's displayed on a terminal, the ones that interpret those escape sequences). Change to `--color=always` to add the colouring even when the output doesn't go to a terminal device.

What attributes and colours are used (bold red by default) is controlled via the `$GREP_COLORS` environment variable (formerly `$GREP_COLOR`).

Call `grep` as `GREP_COLORS='mt=1;41;33' grep...` for instance for the `m`atched `t`ext to be in bold, yellow foreground, red background.

A `printred` function that prints the matching lines in red could then look like:

```
println() { # prints each of its arguments on separate lines
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"
}
printred() {
  println "$@" |
    GREP_COLORS='mt=31' grep --color -Ee '^\s*\{?-.*' -e '^'
}
```

Another way to highlight those lines without relying on GNUisms would be to used `sed` to add the ANSI escape sequences around matching lines with:

```
ESC=$(printf '\33')
printred() {
  if [ -t 1 ]; then
    println "$@" |
      sed "s/^[[:space:]]*{\{0,1\}-.*/${ESC}[31m&${ESC}[m"
  else
    println "$@"
}
```

Or `perl` instead of `sed`:

```
perl -pe 's/^\s*\{?-.*/\e[31m$&\e[m/'
```

Comment: It is good, but want control to set with any colour, than what defined for grep.

Comment: @Heime, see edit.

Comment: I do not want to mess up grep itself.

Comment: Something like `printred` is preferable.  Would you have a solution that also mitigates the problems you mentioned, particularly the command injection vulnerability part?

Comment: @Heime See edit. The command injection vulnerability part in Gilles' answer you could mitigate with great effort by quoting the line in sh syntax before it's passed to sh, but using that `e` flag is certainly the wrong approach. I've added a `sed` approach that doesn't have the issue as it's passing anything dynamically to programming language for it to interpret as code!